# How to use Try Catch Block to catch specific custom exception

Tags: java

I have a CustomException class that looks like so:

```
public class CustomException extends RuntimeException
{
  public CustomException(String message)
  {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

I throw this exception when a certain if condition is met and then in a separate class use a Try Catch Block to print a custom error message like so:

```
catch (CustomException e)
{
    System.out.println("Location already occupied");
}
```

My question is how do I specify within the catch which CustomException I am referring to. If i throw the custom exception with the message parameter as "Tile Out of Bounds" but then throw it again elsewhere with the message parameter as "Tile Location Occupied" how do i catch each one.

Comment: @Carcigenicate could you provide an example of how to do this? not quite sure how I would catch each subclass

Answer (score 1):

You can't literally catch an exception based on its message. To do what you're trying to do, you'd need to subclass your custom exception:

```
public class TileOutOfBoundsException extends CustomException {
    . . .
}

public class TileOccupiedException extends CustomException {
    . . .
}
```

Then catch each subclass,

```
. . .
catch (TileOutOfBoundsException e) {
    System.out.println("Location out of bounds");
}

. . .
catch (TileOccupiedException e) {
    System.out.println("Location occupied");
}
```

Whether or not subclassing is actually appropriate here is another story though and is a matter of opinion.

Your only other alternative that I know of would be to catch the exception, then manually check the message against each case that you want to handle. That would arguably be much messier, and prone to breakage if your ever decided to change the messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to distinguish between various `CustomException` instances then your exception is clearly not specific enough. In that case you should split the `CustomException` into two classes, for instance `CustomException1` and `CustomException2`.

It depends on the type and relation between the exceptions how those exceptions relate to each other. They may be completely separate, they can have a child-parent relationship or they could be siblings under the same parent.

In your case it seems that you can create the following tree using the sibling (shared parent class) approach:

```
public abstract class TileException extends Exception

public class TileOutOfBoundsException extends TileException

public class TileLocationOccupied extends TileException
```

Here the parent class is abstract as it doesn't make much sense to instantiate it without further specification into one of the two (or more) subclasses.

---

If you just need to decide between the two for error handling such as printing out details (rather than making business decisions) then you could also create a field that distinguishes between the two. For instance, you could introduce an `enum Disginguisher` with the fields `ONE` and `TWO` and then create a getDestinguisher()`method for the class. Then you can create a`switch`within the`catch`to choose specific operation, depending on the result of`getDistinguisher()`.

Generally however I would see this as inferior to creating two different exceptions.

---

What you certainly should **not** do is to use `getMessage()` to distinguish between exceptions. Message descriptions may change and using string comparison is error prone. It will also preclude you from adding variable information into the message string.

Answer (score -1):

Catch block in Java choice exception to handle only and only by exception class. Nothing else like error message metter here.

Comment: Here I provide a short but full and comprehensive answer to the question. A big surprise that you could have some complains here.

Comment: Not that it matters much, I think we have a drive-by asker :(